# How to insert python console into tkinter screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, console, python-3.6

I've been trying to do this for ages and can't find a way to do this, even though I have heard it is possible.

I want to be able to **insert** the python console into any tkinter widget (eg. frame, canvas, etc.).

How can I do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S. This is not a duplicate. I do not want to redirect stdout to tkinter text as that doesn't work in while True loops. I need to EMBED the console in tkinter.**

Comment: @2875563 This is not a duplicate. I want to embed the console, not redirect stdout.

Comment: Like the console in idle?

Comment: Preferably like the python interpreter (the black console), but if idle is only what is possible, than that will have to work.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it, but i do know that IDLE is coded in tkinter. Look in idlelib, all of the source code is there.

Comment: I tried that but because I am putting a tkinter fork (IDLE) into a tkinter window, things like `while True` loops don't seem to work.

Comment: Hmm. I will look into this, and come back when I find something.

Comment: Will a custom `tk.Text` widget that imitates idle work? You could embed that pretty much anywhere.

Comment: Look into the `code` module, it might help, and is included in the standard lib, and is the interface to the pyconsole that idle uses.